# Why are frequently occurring events difficult to predict?

Tags: prediction

I can understand this on an intuitive basis, but I'm otherwise not clear on how to think about this more formally.  (Alternately, am I wrong that frequently occurring events are difficult to predict?)

Any insight would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more clear? Can you explain why you affirm this? Indeed I would say the opposite, if in Rainiyland it rains 364 days in a year (very frequently) I would predict tomorrow it will rain and I would have probability $ 99.73% $ to be right and only $ 0.27% $ to be wrong.

Comment: I heard someone suggest this, but perhaps I misinterpreted them. It was in reference to frequent, automatic behaviors being difficult to predict. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually say the opposite, that more commonly occurring events are easier to predict, if by that you mean something like constructing a regression model.

Assuming that the events you're talking about can be broken down into binary 'yes/no' or 'event/no event', I would think of this like a logistic regression. Since tests of binary outcomes are based on number of events observed rather than number of participants, a higher number of events is desirable and permits detecting smaller effects.

The challenge faced by RCT drug trials in detecting adverse events is an example of the problems posed by modelling rare events.

For an example of calculating sample sizes for binary outcomes see:

http://ndt.oxfordjournals.org/content/25/5/1388.long

http://rds.epi-ucsf.org/ticr/syllabus/courses/26/2009/02/03/Other/readings/Wittes_02.pdf